# Android Phone Storage Full due to APKs

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, storage, oxygenos

My OnePlus Two has 64GB Internal Storage and no SD card. 
It shows Phone Storage Full warning. When I investigated, I saw below stats and am unable to free space.

Settings > Storage & Memory > Storage & USB 
Internal Storage 53.62 GB Used of 54.00 GB

*Break Up*

> Apps      14.00 GB
>   Images   565 MB
>   Videos    8.00 KB
>   Audio     44.00 KB
>   **Other      38.94 GB**
>   Cached Data   3.64 MB

I clicked "Others". Next, "Explore" > "File Manager" > "Categories" > "Phone Storage" > "Storage Information".

> Images   170.57 MB
>   Audio      1.98 GB
>   Video      1.02 GB
>   Others    14.9 GB
>   Archives   538.09 KB
>   **Apks          35.46 GB**
>   Documents   117.16 MB
>   Available        339.48 MB

When I check "apks", I see several apks for each app (which are presently installed or were installed in past). It looks like on each update of the apps, the apk file for each update in present on my phone.

I have tried some uninstalling apps but that does not remove all apks. I still see several apks for each app which I uninstall.

Example of apk names.

```
Facebook_140.0.0.24.91.apk  86.2 MB 
Facebook_141.0.0.31.91.apk  86.2 MB 
Facebook_136.0.0.22.91.apk  82.37 MB 
Facebook_135.0.0.22.90.apk  81.79 MB 
Facebook_130.0.0.45.70.apk  81.77 MB 
Facebook_134.0.0.25.91.apk  80.69 MB 
Facebook_132.0.0.20.85.apk  80.55 MB 
Facebook_131.0.0.32.69.apk  79.53 MB 
:: 
:: 
Facebook_114.0.0.20.70.apk  69.49 MB
```

Similarly for each other app on my phone.

OxygenOS `version 3.5.8`
Android Version `6.0.1`
Android Security Patch Level `March 1, 2017`
Kernel Version `3.10.84-perf+
OnePlus@ubuntu-56 #1
Mon Mar 13 11:40:18 CST 2017`
Build Number `ONE A2003_24_170313`

Please help. Any solution other than phone reset ?

Comment: At first glance this seems like a bug in the ROM. Can you give more details about what ROM you have?

Comment: @DanHulme Sorry. Missed OS version in Question. Added it now at the end of my post.

Answer (score -2):

After an apk is installed it can be deleted from a file manager and you keep your apps/games.

Comment: That is the temporary recurring solution I am doing. I thought there could be a way to fix this.